# Why am I getting a 404 at the root domain of my website in IIS 6?

Tags: iis-6, asp.net, http-status-code-404

I have a client who setup SiteMinder on our server and I need to add a web app to the website directory that is the root of the domain. When they browse login.url.com it redirects them to their server, authenticates user, comes back and lands on a 404 page in my IIS. I put the Default.aspx and application files at the Default Website as well as the siteminderagent virtual directory, but they still are getting a 404 error.

[image]

How can I figure out where this application is landing them with a 404?

Also, I installed .NET 3.5 on the server and the app is .NET 3.5, however even after installing it only shows 2.0xx inside the properties window of the default website... do I need to change this?

[image]

Comment: The ASP.NET version is fine as 2.0. I believe this is because .NET 3.5 did not include an update to ASP.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find what you are looking for in the W3SVC logs. You can see the request as it came in and I would think that should be enlightening. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313437

In the logs, check the substatus code for the 404 responses.

404 Substatus 2 in IIS means: *Web service extension lockdown policy prevents this request*.

If this is the case, you probably just need to enable the ASP.NET web service extensions. See here: [404 when page exists - IIS 5, ASP.NET 4.0](https://serverfault.com/questions/29487/404-when-page-exists-iis-5-asp-net-4-0)

Comment: No, the URL is actually the same currently. If you have the cookie you get the 404, if not you go to the client server and get the cookie. If I already know the URL, how can I reverse figure out which place in IIS the URL points to?

Comment: You might find what you are looking for in the W3SVC logs. You can see the request as it came in and I would think that should be enlightening. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313437

Comment: All I see is the requests that came in on port 80 to root '/' but no hints as to why the page installed at this location is not loading. Default.aspx is there with all the required files deployed from VS2010, but I have no idea why I am getting a 404.

Comment: What is the substatus code for the 404 responses? 404 Substatus 2 in IIS means: "Web service extension lockdown policy prevents this request.". If this is the case, you probably just need to enable the ASP.NET web service extensions. See here: http://serverfault.com/questions/29487/404-when-page-exists-iis-5-asp-net-4-0

Comment: I think this might be the problem, ASP.NET 2 was marked as PROHIBITED! Shit I feel really dumb. Just gotta remind myself that my mom doesn't even know the difference between a web page and a PDF so I'm doing pretty good still... hopefully this is the solution, I am waiting to test, then I can award you the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Did that end up being the solution?

Comment: yes the problem was that the web extension for ASP.NET was disabled in IIS :/ Can you edit your answer to be the comment you made about web service extensions?

Comment: @Ryan, good call and done.

Answer (score 0):

Is default.aspx set as a default document for the sites in question? It sounds like it probably isn't assuming everything else is configured correctly.